# Richfaces editor cannot find content.css

Tags: tomcat, ckeditor, richfaces

The rich:editor toolbar renders as a collection of labels rather than the buttons.

The Chrome debug shows that the content.css is returned with a 404.

I am using Richfaces 4.3.7 on Tomcat 7.

On my development machine (Win Pro), I just have Tomcat and the editor renders correctly, however on the server (Debian), Tomcat is behind Apache2 with the requests being routed via mod_jk.

I know that the request is getting through to Tomcat as the mod_jk log shows the successful mapping and the Tomcat access log shows that the requests are being responded to with a 404. In fact the access log shows that all the requests from org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.ckeditor result in a 404 however the ckeditor.js.xhtml etc from javax.faces.resource are returned successfully.

Any suggestions please
Thanks
Mike

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I have broken the relevant files out of the jar into the relevant webapps folder and the editor render as it should

Comment: What does the URL for contents.css look like?